# Bootstrap tagsinput add tag with id and value

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using [Bootstrap Tags Input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

I am trying to add tags dynamically.

```
$('.div-tag').tagsinput('add', 'vino');
```

The above code works fine, but when I try the following code:

```
$('.div-tag').tagsinput('add', { id: 1, text: 'some tag' });
```

I get the error:

`Uncaught Can't add objects when itemValue option is not set`

Please help me to add tag with id and value.

Comment: Have you tried *setting* the *itemValue* field? Like
$('.div-tag').tagsinput('add', { id: 1, itemValue: 'some tag' });

This is how I would interpret the docs at first glance.

Comment: @alexander.biskop Yes i tried this method too and got same error.

Comment: Ah, it seems like this is correct when *adding* items:
$('input').tagsinput('add', { id: 1, text: 'some tag' });

However, you have to specify *itemValue* when you are creating the tags input field like so:
$('input').tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'id'
});

EDIT: I'm referring to the "Options" sections of the docs.

Comment: Sorry could you please elaborate bit more.

Comment: @alexander.biskop check my answer if it is ok then make a vote for my answer.

Comment: Clarified question by improving grammar, words used and layout

Answer (score 18, accepted):

initialize tags input like

```
 $('.div-tag').tagsinput({
      allowDuplicates: false,
        itemValue: 'id',  // this will be used to set id of tag
        itemText: 'label' // this will be used to set text of tag
    });
```

To add dynamic tag

```
$('.div-tag').tagsinput('add', { id: 'tag id', label: 'tag lable' });
```

That's it;

Comment: How to use this with typeahead ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 13):

I spent few hours to find out, that above working only when **data-role="tagsinput"** is removed from your

```
<input class="div-tag" />
```

Comment: This appeared to solve the problem as tags are now loaded into the input field but when adding new tags, they are not recognised as tags.  Seems data-role is required.

Comment: This simple change solved most of the problems I was encountering in my app. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

This library is broken, don't bother. The accepted answer doesn't work on version 0.8. After 1h of trying several things, I suggest to switch to another library, I used [tagEditor](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html) , where everything worked on the 1st try.

Comment: Please don't just post a link to some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I'm not suggesting some other lib, I'm suggesting not to use this one, as it is broken. It is. I could remove the specific recommendation, but I think it helps. It would have helped me. Including a demo from the other lib would be out of scope.

Comment: Even I think the library is broken. When you try to add tags later after initialization, it won't add the first tag, but the following tags I am trying to add. (At least in my case). Further, after you add those tags the tags editor seems to become reset, as in properties such as `freeInput` I have set to `false` during initialization, doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the library, but when you get this error it means there is a problem with the method initilization.

Try to do it when the page is ready like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myInput').tagsinput({
       allowDuplicates: false,
       itemValue: 'id',
       itemText: 'label'
    });
});

$(".someButton").click(function(){
   $('#myInput').tagsinput('add', {id:1, label:"blah blah"});
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Please try like this:

```
<div data-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/index_slide01.jpg">
    <div class="fadeIn camera_caption">
        <h2 class="text_1 color_1">Solutions that you need!</h2>
        <a class="btn_1" href="#">More info</a>
    </div>
</div>
```