# Add new tags using Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Tags: jquery, meteor, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)

I am trying to add tags dynamically in my meteor project, I referred [Bootstrap tagsinput add tag with id and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703773/bootstrap-tagsinput-add-tag-with-id-and-value), but still got the same error.

```
Uncaught Can't add objects when itemValue option is not set
```

The code I used is:

```
$("input[name='skills']").tagsinput({
    typeahead: {
            source: data,
            itemValue: 'id', 
            itemText: 'label' ,
        },
});
$('input[name="skills"]').tagsinput('add', { id: 'tag id', label: 'tag lable' });
```

I also tried to add tags using [addItem](https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/1S0K3w3L06081E0K2G0b/addItem.png) option in [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead), but couldn't make it

```
$("input[name='skills']").tagsinput({
    typeahead: {
            source: data
        },
     addItem: true,
});
```

Can any body help me to add new tags along with Bootstrap-3-Typeahead, Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same problem. It seems not to work